# How to calculate sum on unique values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

So here's the data:

**DF1**

```
ID  DOW     
1   Monday
1   Monday
1   Tuesday
2   Tuesday
2   Wednesday
3   Friday
3   Monday
3   Tuesday
```

I would like to join the following dictionary.

**DF2**

```
ID DOW        Hours
1  Monday     20
1  Tuesday    21
2  Tuesday    30
2  Wednesday  25
3  Friday     24
3  Monday     42
3  Tuesday    54
```

My goal is I want the total count of entries on each day as well as the hours worked on that day. But if a value on the list exists twice, it is not counted twice. (Thats the hard part)

Here's my attempt following R Code:

```
df3 <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("DOW" ,"ID"))

df3 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize(count = n())
            sum = sum(Employee_Hrs)) %>% 
  mutate(injRate = count/sum)
```

This does not work because though it does successfully count total number of entries for each ID, it sums  employee_Hrs every time, even when it is entered multiple times...

End product should be:

```
ID count    sum
1      3     41
2      2     55
3      3    120
```

Again, take count, but sum hours , dont double count.

Comment: It should work if you do the group_by %>% summarize on df2 only. Why don't you join df1 afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to summarize the tables prior to joining them.

```
textFile1 <- "ID  DOW     
1   Monday
1   Monday
1   Tuesday
2   Tuesday
2   Wednesday
3   Friday
3   Monday
3   Tuesday"

textFile2 <- "ID DOW        Hours
1  Monday     20
1  Tuesday    21
2  Tuesday    30
2  Wednesday  25
3  Friday     24
3  Monday     42
3  Tuesday    54"
df1 <- read.table(text =textFile1,header=TRUE )
df2 <- read.table(text =textFile2,header=TRUE )

df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>%
        summarise(count = n()) -> counts 
df2 %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     summarize(sum = sum(Hours)) %>% 
     left_join(counts) %>% 
     mutate(injRate = count/sum)
```

...and the output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     ID   sum count injRate
  <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>
1     1    41     3  0.0732
2     2    55     2  0.0364
3     3   120     3  0.025
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution where you compute the number of counts and then you filter to obtain final summary:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df3 <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("DOW" ,"ID"))
#Code
df3 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(count=n()) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(DOW)) %>%
  summarise(count=unique(count),Sum=sum(Hours))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     ID count   Sum
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     3    41
2     2     2    55
3     3     3   120
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `merge` + `aggregate`

```
u <- merge(df1, df2, by = c("ID", "DOW"))
res <- setNames(
  merge(aggregate(DOW ~ ID, u, length),
    aggregate(Hours ~ ID, unique(u), sum),
    by = "ID"
  ),
  c("ID", "Count", "Sum")
)
```

which gives

```
> res
  ID Count Sum
1  1     3  41
2  2     2  55
3  3     3 120
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, .(Count = .N, Hours), on = .(ID), by = .EACHI][,
    .(Sum = sum(Hours)), .(ID, Count)]
#   ID Count Sum
#1:  1     3  41
#2:  2     2  55
#3:  3     3 120
```